# Select column from table1 which is not in table2

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two table

```
table1
=======================================
tid    subcategory     category
---------------------------------------
1      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY1
2      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY2
3      SUBCATEGORY2    CATEGORY1
4      SUBCATEGORY3    CATEGORY1
5      SUBCATEGORY4    CATEGORY1
6      SUBCATEGORY5    CATEGORY1
7      SUBCATEGORY6    CATEGORY1
8      SUBCATEGORY7    CATEGORY1
9      SUBCATEGORY8    CATEGORY1
10     SUBCATEGORY9    CATEGORY1


table2
=======================================
t2id   subcategory     category  pid
---------------------------------------
1      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY1  1
2      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY2  1
3      SUBCATEGORY2    CATEGORY1  1
```

I try to show all rows of table1 which is not in table2, the result should be like this...

```
=======================================
tid    subcategory     category
---------------------------------------
4      SUBCATEGORY3    CATEGORY1
5      SUBCATEGORY4    CATEGORY1
6      SUBCATEGORY5    CATEGORY1
7      SUBCATEGORY6    CATEGORY1
8      SUBCATEGORY7    CATEGORY1
9      SUBCATEGORY8    CATEGORY1
10     SUBCATEGORY9    CATEGORY1
```

I am using this query...

```
select tl.* from table1 tl where subcategory and category not in(SELECT tl.subcategory, tl.category  FROM table1 as tl join table2 as bm where bm.pid='1' and tl.subcategory=bm.subcategory and tl.category=bm.category);
```

but it not working help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```
SELECT t1.tid, t1.subcategory, t1.category
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.pim = 1 AND
                        t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory AND t2.category = t1.category);
```

Comment: can you tell me here what is the meaning of SELECT 1

Comment: `SELECT 1` would just return a record with a single column having the value 1, but the logic here is checking for existence of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  Read about exists for more information on the syntax.